# Use raspberry as audio sink

Tags: wifi, audio, streaming, pulseaudio

I'd like to know if there is a good way to set the raspberry and use it as audio network sink and send streams from wifi devices (win8 pc or tablet, android devices, linux pc). I'm already using the raspberry as access point.
I tried with the instruction in [this page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=11124&sid=0352a7aaccea7d63a4d6109c88ec8beb) using pulseaudio but with no success.
Then I discovered there's many alternatives, one of which is dlna.
My question is: which of the alternatives works best for my requirements? (multiplatform sources, already using raspberry as AP over tp-link wifi card model tl-wn722n with 150Mbps

Answer (score 3):

This site isn't made for "which works best for my requirements" as this is highly subjective and likely to change, but a couple of alternatives are:

- [Volumio](http://volumio.org) - mpd-based, web interface, supports queuing and has a browser interface
- [RuneAudio](http://www.runeaudio.com) - also mpd-based, web interface, based on same code as Volumio but with different features (I use this one)

Both these installs include DLNA servers, web-queues, AirPlay and OpenHome support, and you can just control the playback via a web interface from any device (even from the Internet if you're so inclined). DO NOTE that both of them are full OS images, so you couldn't just add it on to your current setup, you would have to recreate your AP setup within the image.

- [Kodi](http://kodi.tv) - This is the new name of XMBC, which is a full media center allowing you to play your music as well. I believe it features AirPlay and a DLNA renderer. Does not have a built-in web interface, works best if directly connected to a TV/monitor. There is a web-addon but I haven't had much success. The upside is that this is very widely supported.